# Flutter: PlatformException (PlatformException(, cannot find the file, null, null)) on FlutterAudioRecorder2

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-audio-query

```
class AudioRecorder {
  static DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  static String timestamp = now.toString();
  var recorder = FlutterAudioRecorder2("./file_path",
      audioFormat: AudioFormat.AAC); 
  // or var recorder = FlutterAudioRecorder2("file_path.mp3");
  startRecording() async {
    await recorder.initialized;
    await recorder.start(); // <- error here
  }

  stopRecording() async {
    var result = await recorder.stop();
  }
}
```

I can't find a way to fix [image: this error], mainly because I don't understand what does it means, why it says "cannot find the file"  but the file needs to be created? (since it's a recording?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few points I noticed are

1. Please check if its initialised or not in the initstate

```
await recorder.initialized;
//after initialisation add this
var current = await recorder.current(channel: 0);
//you should get the current status as initialised if its done properly.
```

2. then on start recording use

```
await recorder.start()
```

Also make sure that the file path is right

**Edit**
This is the code to init the recorder

```dart
_init() async {
    try {
      bool hasPermission = await FlutterAudioRecorder2.hasPermissions ?? false;

      if (hasPermission) {
        String customPath = '/flutter_audio_recorder_';
        io.Directory appDocDirectory;
//        io.Directory appDocDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        if (io.Platform.isIOS) {
          appDocDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        } else {
          appDocDirectory = (await getExternalStorageDirectory())!;
        }

        // can add extension like ".mp4" ".wav" ".m4a" ".aac"
        customPath = appDocDirectory.path + customPath + DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();

        _recorder = FlutterAudioRecorder2(customPath, audioFormat: AudioFormat.AAC);

        await _recorder!.initialized;
        // after initialization
        var current = await _recorder!.current(channel: 0);
        print(current);
        // should be "Initialized", if all working fine
      } else {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(content: Text("You must accept permissions")));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Does _recorder is the same as recorder?

Comment: yeah its the same.. sorry I missed it.. Editing my answer

Comment: current.status is 'RecordingStatus.Initialized' but I still got the same error

Comment: The file does not exist, it must be created by recording from the microphone, what do you mean by the right file path?

Comment: Updated my answer with full init method